# Smallest, toy, Distributed version control system to study

Tags: git, version-control

I am interested in writing a toy DVCS.  
What is the smallest DVCS around to study ? 
(I don't need ssl, ssh, svn compatibility etc... it should just be able to do local repositories)

Comment: Why did you tag this `git`? Surely you're not suggesting here that git is a toy? That would be a brave move here amongst the giterati :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: Well, the *actual* core of Git is tiny. Or rather it *would be* tiny if it weren't written in a 40 year old pseudo-macro-assembler but in a "real", "modern" programming language. So, if Git weren't written in C, it would definitely fit the bill. [BTW: please read this the same way it was written: with a good sense of humor. Thank you.]

Comment: @paxdiablo: i am biased.  I have only ever used git for a vcs.
@Mittag: I actually like c. The msvc .sln available with msysgit make it much easier to browse and explore the source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual core of Git is rather small. Unfortunately, it's not written in a programming language that is amenable to easy understanding, and it is riddled with performance optimizations that are not relevant to the actual operation.

However, there are several alternative implementations of Git, in particular the [Dulwich](https://Launchpad.Net/Dulwich/) library, which is written in Python.

There's also [Amp](http://Amp.Carboni.ca/), whose goal is to provide unified interfaces to all major distributed version control systems. At the moment, they only implement Mercurial, but Git, Bazaar and Darcs are planned as well. Now, Mercurial is written in Python and Amp in Ruby which are both similarly expressive, so you might think that the difference isn't that big. However, Amp is designed so that you e.g. use the Mercurial commands on a Git repository or Darcs commands with Bazaar semantics on a Mercurial repository, so there is a *very clear* separation between those layers. *And* Amp is designed so that even non-programmers can write their own personalized version control system using Amp's building blocks, so the code is *extremely* simple and straightforward.

Comment: Now *that* (i.e. Amp), I would consider it as the right answer for this question. +1

Comment: unfortunately dulwich isn't complete... git-merge is not implemented, which is the part of git i am most awed by. 
Out of the remaining implementations: https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Interfaces,_frontends,_and_tools#Interfaces_to_other_programming_languages    It looks like msysgit and jgit are the most mature. msysgit is nicely browsable with an msvc .sln file.

Answer (score 2):

The initial version of git

```
commit e83c5163316f89bfbde7d9ab23ca2e25604af290
Author: Linus Torvalds <torvalds@ppc970.osdl.org>
Date:   Thu Apr 7 15:13:13 2005 -0700
```

had 1,064 lines of code (ansic=822,sh=242).

For a chronicle, see:

- http://userweb.kernel.org/~junio/200810-Chron.pdf

Initially making a commit looked like this:

```
$ init-db 
$ edit file 
$ update-cache –-add file 
$ edit file 
$ show-diff 
$ update-cache file 
$ T=$(write-tree) 
$ P=$(cat .dircache/HEAD) 
$ C=$(echo "My commit" | commit-tree $T -p $P) 
$ echo $C >.dircache/HEAD
```

Comment: Yes, but its early design and interface were so divergent from most VCSes or DVCS ideas that I don't know that it would be overly helpful for DVCS educational purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at fossil distributed versioning it's only 350kb.

http://www.fossil-scm.org

Answer (score 1):

[Darcs](http://darcs.net/) is written in Haskell, but it is quite large: 40 KLOC. Mercurial is about 40 KLOC too, but its core is about 20 KLOC.